# ¿Cómo centrar div que contiene un background-image?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Estoy intentando centrar un `div` que contiene una imagen con la propiedad de css `background-imagen:url(url);` pero no consigo centrar el div, este solamente se centraría si le doy como propiedad que tenga un `width:100%;` pero no quiero eso ya que expande la imagen a todo el ancho del `div`.

Adjunto mi código y la propidad css.

```
<div class="row mt-2 mb-4">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
        
        @if($empleado->avatar != 'avatar_default.png')
            <div class="frame rounded-circle mt-2" style="background-image: url('{{ asset('/empleados/avatars/'.$empleado->id.'/'.$empleado->avatar) }}');">
        
            </div>
            {{-- <img src="{{ asset('empleados/avatars/'.$empleado->id.'/'.$empleado->avatar) }}" alt="" class="img-fluid rounded-circle mt-2" style="width:120px !important;height:120px !important;"> --}}
        @else
            <div class="frame rounded-circle mt-2" style="background-image: url('{{ asset('/empleados/'.$empleado->avatar) }}');">
        
            </div>
            {{-- <img src="{{ asset('empleados/'.$empleado->avatar) }}" alt="" class="img-fluid rounded-circle mt-2" style="width:120px !important;height:120px !important;"> --}}
        @endif
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Los signos `{{-- --}}` son comentarios en laravel. Estoy usando bootstrap como herramienta para dar estilo al sitio web.

La clase `.frame` tiene estas propiedades:

```
.frame{width: 100px;height:100px;background: transparent no-repeat center;background-size: cover;text-align:center !important;float:right;}
```

Aquí una captura de como se está visualizando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Centrar de forma horizontal o vertical?

Comment: de forma horizontal @BetaM

Comment: Prueba con la clase [**`mx-auto`**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/#horizontal-centering) que se indica en la propia doc. de bootstrap

Comment: Lo he probado pero tampoco ha sido un éxito @BetaM

Comment: Probaste colocando .frame {margin: auto} y eliminando el float: right;?

Comment: Sí de hecho cuando añado `margin:auto` este ocupa todo el ancho ya que uso la propiedad de css `background-image:url(url);` porque no es una imagen simple sino que está añadida en un div para evitar la distorsión de la imagen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo usaría Flexbox. Para ello, al contenedor de ambos elementos (texto e imagen) agrega los siguientes estilos CSS:

```
.contenedor {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Con esto se colocarían en columna y centrados horizontalmente.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @Gabri me ha resuelto el problema! Gracias a todos por contribuir.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que usar Flexbox es la mejor forma, la respuesta de Gabri lo deja bastante claro, sin embargo puedo dejarte otra opción aunque no es la más recomendable.

```
.frame {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    left: 50%;
}
```

Corrijo, esto centrará la imagen de forma horizontal, después tendrás que asignar un alto